# MEAN stack app using Meetup.api - "Meetup.getCategories is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the Meetups.com API in my node app, and I'm trying to return a JSON list of all of the event categories, but Angular keeps returning, "angular.js:13708 TypeError: Meetup.getCategories is not a function"

Here's my controller for the events page:

```
angular
  .module("Londate")
  .controller("EventsController", EventsController);

EventsController.$inject = ["$state", "TokenService", "$rootScope", "Meetup"];
function EventsController($state, TokenService, $rootScope, Meetup) {
  var self = this;

  this.mapCenter = { lat: 51.5, lng: -0.1 };

  this.category = 1;

  this.allCategories = [];

  this.all = [];

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {
      self.mapCenter = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      }

      self.getEvents();
    });
  });

  this.getEvents = function() {
    Meetup.getEvents({
      lat: self.mapCenter.lat,
      lng: self.mapCenter.lng,
      category: self.category
    })
    .then(function(events) {
      console.log("EVENTS: " + events);
      self.all = events;
    })
  }

  this.getCategories = function() {
    Meetup.getCategories({
      name: self.name
    })
    .then(function(categories){
      console.log("CATEGORIES: " + categories);
      self.allCategories = categories;
    })
  }

  self.getCategories();

}
```

And the Meetup.js controller on the backend:

```
var request = require('request-promise');

function getEvents(req, res) {

  request.get({
    url: "https://api.meetup.com/2/open_events",
    qs: {
      key: process.env.MEETUP_API_KEY,
      lat: req.query.lat,
      lon: req.query.lng,
      category: req.query.category,
      radius: req.query.radius || 1,
      sign: true
    },
    json: true
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    res.status(200).json(response.results);
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json(err);
  })
}

function getCategories(req, res) {

  request.get({
    url: "https://api.meetup.com/2/categories",
    qs: {
      key: process.env.MEETUP_API_KEY,
      name: req.query.name,
      sign: true
    },
    json: true
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    res.status(200).json(response.results);
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json(err);
  })
}

module.exports = {
  getEvents: getEvents,
  getCategories: getCategories
}
```

And the meetup.js service on the frontend:

```
angular
  .module("Londate")
  .service("Meetup", Meetup)

Meetup.inject = ["$http"];
function Meetup($http) {
  this.getEvents = function(params) {
    return $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/api/meetups",
      params: params
    })
    .then(function(res) {
      return res.data;
    });
  };
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I neglected to include getCategories in the service, as such:

```
angular
  .module("Londate")
  .service("Meetup", Meetup)

Meetup.inject = ["$http"];
function Meetup($http) {
  this.getEvents = function(params) {
    return $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/api/meetups/events",
      params: params
    })
    .then(function(res) {
      return res.data;
    });
  };

  this.getCategories = function() {
    return $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/api/meetups/categories"
    })
    .then(function(res) {
      return res.data;
    });
  }
}
```